# What is the use of DispatcherPriority.Invalid and DispatcherPriority.InActive?

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

Having trouble understanding what are the uses of DispatcherPriority.Invalid and DispatcherPriority.InActive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) states that `Inactive` means that "operations are not processed," which corresponds to a priority of zero, and `Invalid` pretty much means what it says.

Note that in [this Priority Queue code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Base/MS/Internal/PriorityQueue@cs/1305600/PriorityQueue@cs), Invalid is used as a return state for the `MaxPriority` method when the queue contains no Priority Chains.